svelteKit with dropzone
I'm setting dropzone with svelteKit and I'm getting some issues with the preview image, thiis my code:
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import Dropzone from 'dropzone';
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

  import 'dropzone/dist/dropzone.css';
  import 'dropzone/dist/basic.css';

  let dropzone;
  let previewUrl = writable(null);
  let currentFile = null;

  onMount(() => {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    dropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
      url: "/upload",
      maxFiles: 1,
      acceptedFiles: 'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png',
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", (file) => {
          if (file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
            currentFile = file;
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
              previewUrl.set(e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
        });

        this.on("removedfile", () => {
          previewUrl.set(null);
          currentFile = null;
        });
      }
    });
  });

</script>

<style>
  .dz-preview .dz-image {
    display: none;
  }
  .custom-preview {
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .dropzone {
    border: 2px dashed rgb(209, 208, 208);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .dropzone .dz-message {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: gray;
  }
  .btn-remove {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .dropzone:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
</style>

<div id="dropzone" class="dropzone">
  {#if $previewUrl === null}
    <div class="dz-message">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">        
        <i class="col-12 bi bi-cloud-upload fs-1 text-center"></i>
        <span class="col-12 text-center fw-bold" style="font-size: 13px;">Frag and Drop some image</span>
        <span class="col-12" style="font-size: 13px;"> o </span>
        <button class="col-5 btn btn-primary text-center" style="font-size: 13px;" on:click={() => document.querySelector('#dropzone input[type="file"]').click()}>Selecciona Imagen</button>
        <span class="fst-italic mt-2" style="font-size: 12px;"> Max 10 MB. Format JPG, PNG</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  {/if}
</div>

and I'm getting this:

I'm importing the css:
  import 'dropzone/dist/dropzone.css';
  import 'dropzone/dist/basic.css';

what wrong? why I can't see the correct form the image? why is black bar in the middle of the image
